# What is the best way for assigning 2 different type object arrays to eachother in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to assign 2 different type array to eachother attribute by attribute.
Can someone explain me what is the best way for this purpose? I am using the code below, but when I have too much attribute , it does not good look.  How can I map attributes easily?

```
    export interface ClassA {
        Type: string;
        Name: string;
    }

    export interface ClassB {
        Typ: string; 
        Nm: string; 
    }



    let  items: ClassA[] = [
    { Type: 'T1', Name: 'N1'},
    { Type: 'T2', Name: 'N2'},
    { Type: 'T3', Name: 'N3'},
    ];

     
    let  items2:ClassB [] = [];


   items.forEach((item, index) => {
            let obj: ClassB  = {Typ:item.Type, Nm:item.Name };
            items2.push(obj);          
        });

console.log(items2);
```

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `forEach`.

Comment: How can I do thsis? I have 2 different type class. Map will work in the case that they have the same type? If they are both from ClassA , map will eork but now how can I use map?

Comment: No, you can map from one type to another.

Comment: Is there any example that you can show?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead since you can map from one type to another type with it. With explicit type annotations, it also gives you inference and typechecking in the map predicate as well:

```
let items2: ClassB[] = items.map((item) => ({ Typ: item.Type, Nm: item.Name }));
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXjG1m)